# Problem loading certain sites in Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

For some reason certain sites just won't load in Tor even though I know they are up and running.

One example- Modelmayhem.com always times out. even if I enable java and cookies. Are they blocking Tor or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Many clearweb sites block known Tor exit nodes to prevent abuse. VPN's are better for accessing blocked content on the clearweb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does seem that they block Tor.

Try https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy via Tor. Just remember that they won't really hide your ass ;)